# React "string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined."

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn React with Chatgpt and I'm making sample projects. Error message:

string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:

> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the rendering method of App.

How can I fix this error?

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-react-project-error-2-vz2lwj?file=/src/App.js) Link

I checked the paths but they are all correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using react-router-dom v6.16.0, but your code is written for v5. v6 does not have a `<Switch>` component, so that's where the undefined import is coming from. And while it does have a `<Route>` component, you're not using it in a way v6 would expect. Additionally, `NotFound.js` is an empty file, so `<Route component={NotFound} />` is passing undefined into the route.

You can fix the version mismatch two ways

Option 1: use react-router-dom v5 (eg, v5.3.4). In codesandbox you do this from the "Dependencies" section on the bottom left

Option 2: rewrite your code to use v6:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
// ...

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <nav>
          <a href="/">Ana Sayfa</a>
          <a href="/about">Hakkında</a>
          <a href="/contact">İletişim</a>
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
          {/* <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} /> */}
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank u so much Nicholas. I fixed this. I tried this solution(i changed version) in another project too but now i have parsing error. What can i do?https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-projekt-1-error-29hkwp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You need a closing `/` on `<Route path="/" element={<NotEkle />}>`. Ie, `<Route path="/" element={<NotEkle />} />`

Comment: This work with old version. How can i coding with new version? I must just change Switch to Routes?